# How could I debug C++ MPI code?

Tags: c++, mpi

My [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)  code compiles with no problem:

But when running, I have issues. I am not sure which line in my code causes this problem. What could I do?

```
[dhcp-18-189-36-128:80590] *** Process received signal ***
[dhcp-18-189-36-128:80590] Signal: Floating point exception: 8 (8)
[dhcp-18-189-36-128:80590] Signal code: Integer divide-by-zero (7)
[dhcp-18-189-36-128:80590] Failing at address: 0x10e4cab9f
[dhcp-18-189-36-128:80590] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff8d0185aa _sigtramp + 26
[dhcp-18-189-36-128:80590] *** End of error message ***
```

Comment: any more information/video tutorial I could follow?

Comment: And what do you want? You have two messages: _Float point exception: 8 (8)_ and _Integer divide-by-zero_ (7). I think it is start point for looking for your errors.

Comment: you will need to recompile your code, and maybe even your mpi library, with debugging symbols.  a tool like valgrind can help.

Comment: There is an excellent overview in the [OpenMPI FAQ](http://www.open-mpi.de/faq/?category=debugging).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to put unit tests around your code to verify it functions correctly in a context smaller than your entire application.  If you are new to unit testing and test-driven development, you can look at my [tutorial on test-driven development from C++ Now! 2014](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/c-now-2014-presentations-posted/).

To elaborate further: when faced with a bug, I try to write a failing unit test that demonstrates the bug.  It's hard to make a specific recommendation of what test to write without seeing any code, but I suggest you start by running your code in the debugger and setting the debugger to treat any floating point exception signal as a breakpoint.  When the breakpoint is hit due to the signal, examine the call stack at that point.  Then you will know what code is causing the signal.  Then you can write a unit test that calls that code with the same arguments.  Your unit test should now fail by reproducing the problem and causing the same divide-by-zero signal.  Then you can change your implementation and re-run the test to verify that the signal is no longer caused.